# Using TEXT or even MEDIUMTEXT for all text columns in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm using a PHP script to insert millions of rows into a MySQL. Each of the rows contain a diversity of columns that are very different across the rows.

Basically I'm using MySQL as a key-value pair store.

While I can make the column to auto-adjust its size according to the length of the string to be inserted on the fly, it may not be a good idea when the table has millions of rows.

For example, with 5 million rows in the table, the next insert has a column with over 5,000 characters while that column is defined as VARCHAR(127) in the table. Re-defining the column in the job would be anything but desirable. Is it? Cause' it bogs things down and it has to change that particular column of all the 5 million rows. Right?

So I'm thinking of creating each column as a TEXT or even MEDIUMTEXT column in the first place. It is after I have done all the inserts that the columns will be re-defined according to the longest value in the column.

Therefore my question is could there be any performance issues with all the columns of the table defined as TEXT / MEDIUMTEXT? Especially for large amounts of inserts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drawbacks of what you propose:

- Temp tables (for complex `SELECTs`) cannot use `MEMORY`, which is faster than the fallback of `MyISAM`.
- Storing numeric 'values' `VARCHAR` makes it difficult or slow to test for.
- Key-value schema leads to ugly `JOINs`.  And they are inefficient.
- In InnoDB, depending on the `ROW_FORMAT`, `TEXT` fields may be stored in other blocks.  This *may* slow you down (`INSERTs` and `SELECTs`) due to extra disk hits.

Yes/no -- the `ALTER TABLE` to change the width of a `VARCHAR` may be costly.  In some very recent version, increasing the size of a `VARCHAR` became virtually free.  (There may be more caveats.)

Comment: I find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472004/mysql-innodb-varchar-performance-versus-text-on-inserts) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628660/text-vs-varchar-in-innodb-mysql-5-5-when-to-use-each-one). Seems it's not something major to worry about? I'm using InnoDB.

Comment: `TEXTs` and long `VARCHARs` prevent use of `MEMORY`, leading to the slower `MyISAM`.  Bottom line:  Use `VARCHAR/VARBINARY` for short columns; use `TEXT/BLOB` when you need bigger fields.  `TEXT/BLOB` cost something in performance.  Should you "worry about it"?  There are more important things to worry about.  "MySQL as a key-value pair store" is the thing to worry about.